# How do I hide / unhide comment section in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I need to hide some comments which cannot be collapsed in some cases. What is the best practice to do it?

```
#region test
//var a = "comment";
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some methods. But I prefer is using these two, since they are manageable:

1. **Hide Selection** command using shortcut keys:
   Simply select your code either it's comment or working code and the just press:

   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>   -> to hide (this simply collapse your selected section and make small box preview)

   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> -> to uhide
2. Try using region:

   `#region region_name`

   ```
    //your stuff
   ```

   `#endregion`

Comment: Consider mentioning _which_ keyboard shortcut you are using.  Not everyone has the defaults for **Edit.Hide Selection**

Comment: @MickyD It's a windows OS configuration key.

Comment: Hope you don't mind but I have edited your answer.  But yes, `Ctrl+M, Ctrl+H` is only recognised by Visual Studio as far as I am aware and interpreted as the default keyboard assignment for **Edit.Hide Selection**.  Visual Studio also allows you to re-define the keyboard shortcut for it and many other commands.